# Autodisplay custom format invoice no in PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can I make MySQL auto increment in 4 digit format?
So instead of '1' make '0001'? and Inv-0001?
This invoice no was also display in text value by default while page loading.

Comment: @DevNiels your answer is a legitimate option, I don't know why you deleted it.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to keep using the same auto increment column, and use [LPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) to pad the left of the `id` column with zeroes, whenever you need your four digit ID in the presentation layer.  Note that `LPAD` accepts a *string* argument, not a numeric one, so you should cast the `id` column first to `CHAR` before calling it:

```
SELECT LPAD(CAST(id AS CHAR(4)), 4, '0')
FROM yourTable
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: hi Tim Biegeleisen, i am new to php.$query = "insert into idgen(name,address) values(''$name','$address')";$insert = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

Comment: hi Tim Biegeleisen, i am new to php this is my code.$query = "insert into idgen(stdid,name,address) values('$stdid','$name','$address')";$insert = mysqli_query($conn,$query); stdid is primary key. i want this id generate custom format and while loading form this id value want to show bydefault in particular textbox. i need full source code.

Comment: Inserting has nothing to do with your problem, since you won't even be assigning the auto increment value yourself.  My answer helps you to get zero padding when you _query_ data from your MySQL table.

Answer (score 0):

Use zerofill attribute:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  prefix CHAR(2),
  number INT(5) ZEROFILL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (number)
);

INSERT INTO my_table (prefix) VALUES ('XX'), ('XX'), ('XX');

SELECT concat(number,prefix) FROM my_table;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d79b7/43)

Comment: ,..i just need to auto generate id like abc101,abc102,abc103,....abc10n and it should be store in DB table. and also it should be show in any textbox at runtime .

Comment: For generating id like abc102,...... use AUTO_INCREMENT=100 and in prefix insert 'abc' with prefix CHAR(3)